# MVC5 Referencing ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I was coding a MVC4 with EF application and is now in the process of upgrading it to MVC5 with EF. In MVC4 I followed a tutorial which created a DBContext as shown below(IssueContext.cs). I know that in MVC5 with Identity our DBContext must derive from IdentityDbContext. I'm having trouble referencing the IdentityDbContext in my Seed method.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;
using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext> <-- References the old one
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext context)<--References the old one
    {



 //Errors on users (new users { FirstMidName.....})
        var users = new List<ApplicationUser>
    {
        new users { FirstMidName = "Jason",   LastName = "Wan",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1, DepotID = 1,IsAdministrator = true},
        new users { FirstMidName = "Andy", LastName = "Domagas",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1,DepotID = 1,IsAdministrator = true},
        new users { FirstMidName = "Denis",   LastName = "Djohar",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1 ,DepotID = 1,IsAdministrator = true },
        new users { FirstMidName = "Christine",   LastName = "West",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 2, DepotID = 3,IsAdministrator = false},

    };

 //Errors on UserID (... = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID <--HERE)
        var tickets = new List<Ticket>
        {
            new Ticket {
                UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,
                CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.CategoryName == "Con-X" ).CategoryID,
                Issue = ("Con-X Login Error"),
                Priority = Priority.High
            },
            new Ticket {
                UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,
                CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.CategoryName == "Desktop" ).CategoryID,
                Issue = ("Can't remote access C0123"),
                Priority = Priority.Med
            },
        };
```

> The type or namespace name 'DAL' does not exist in the namespace
>   'RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem' (are you missing an assembly
>   refernce?)

DAL\IssueContext.cs (Old Data Class Context from MVC4)

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL
{
    public class IssueContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Depot> Depots { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        }
    }
}
```

Models\IdentityModels.cs (New Class MVC5 with Identity

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models
    {
        public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {
            public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> 
                GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
            {
                var userIdentity = await manager
                    .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                return userIdentity;
            }

            public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }
            [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]

            public string LastName { get; set; }
            [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

            [Column("FirstName")]
            public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

            public string FullName
            {
                get { return FirstMidName + " " + LastName; }
            }
            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
            public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
            public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
            public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
            public int DepotID { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
            public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        }


        public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
        {
            public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
            public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name) { }
            public string Description { get; set; }

        }


        public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public ApplicationDbContext()
                : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
            {
            }


            public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Depot> Depots { get; set; }

            static ApplicationDbContext()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
            }

            public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
            {
                return new ApplicationDbContext();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add Using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem: ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still referencing the old `namespace` and class. You need to change it to the new context. And since you are already including the `using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models` then all you need to do is remove the old referenced namespace.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;
using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models; // this is the namespace that has the new context
using System.Collections.Generic;

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext> //References the new one now
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)//References the new one now
    {...}
    //...other code removed for prebity
}
```

Comment: After applying your solution I got 2 new errors `'ApplicationUser' does not contain a definition for 'UserID' and no extension method 'UserID' accepting a first argument of type 'ApplcationUser' could be found (and you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` You can see the errors labeled in my Seed Method. I thought Identity user has it's own UserID? Is it because Identity uses String instead of int?

Comment: Not not because of the string. Identity has an `Id` not UserId`. Remember you are changing from a previous version so there will be differences. The errors are in most cases self explanatory. go through them and make the necessary changes.

Comment: But since changing it to `UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,` to `UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").Id` because IdentityModel's default type is string does that mean I have to follow this site :http://johnatten.com/2014/07/13/asp-net-identity-2-0-extending-identity-models-and-using-integer-keys-instead-of-strings/ or can I cast it? `toString()`?

Comment: it is possible but will require you to make customizations from Identity's default.

Comment: looked at site and seems like you can try to follow what they did. that way you can keep id as int like you wanted.